# CakePHP flash messages triggering late

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a CakePHP 2.5.1 website (although I've tested with an updated 2.10.18 version) running on PHP 5.3.29 (I know, old stuff).

The issue I'm having is that flash messages, **seemingly at random** (but most of the times), don't show when they're supposed to, they show after I reload the page once more (or load a different page).

For example, when a user logs out (I use the **Auth component**), I have set up a flash message like `$this->Session->setFlash('Logout successful');`. So, in normal circumstances, the user clicks the logout link, gets redirected to the home page of the site, and that message shows as a javascript alert. This is how I have this implemented:

```
<?php if( $this->Session->check('Message.flash') ){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>')</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Problem is, that doesn't happen every time, just sometimes. Other times, no flash message is shown at all, but if I refresh the page (or navigate to a different page of the same site), **THEN** the message shows.

I don't know what may be causing this, or how to troubleshoot it since it seems to happen at random. I've tried disabling the cache and enabling debug mode (2) in the core.php file but nothing changes. The site uses **database sessions** in case that matters.

Any help figuring out this situation would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Turns out the hosting provider had enabled some PHP-FPM caching setting that was messing sessions up, after they disabled it everything works fine again

Comment: Have you tried a different session backend? Have you tried manually querying the database to see whether your session values are actually present? Are you maybe using replication?

Comment: @ndm yes I have checked the database and sessions seem fine there. Talking to the hosting provider they've done some adjustments to mod_expires caching settings and looks like it's better now, so it might be a caching issue, gonna keep testing.

Answer (score 0):

I use this way, passing parameters in setFlash, hope that help.

```
<!-- CONTROLLER -->
<?php
if (logout) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Logout success!', 'default', array(), 'Success');
    return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'path/path', 'action' => 'main'));
}
?>

<!-- VERIFICATION IN VIEW (USING BOOTSTRAP )-->
<?php if (($this->Session->check('Message.Success'))) { ?>
    <!-- START: Return message -->
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <?php echo $this->Session->flash('Success'); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Return message -->
<?php } ?>
```